# Is it possible to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=y^x$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve the equation below just for curiosity,

$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^x$

I found that i could only equate $y^x$ with $e^{-i^2x\ln(y)}=\cos(ix\ln(y))-i\sin(ix\ln(y))$, so the original equation became,

$\frac{dy}{dx}+i\sin(ix\ln(y))=\cos(ix\ln(y))$

After I arrived here I couldn't continue.

Can someome solve this problem, please?

Comment: $y=0$ is a solution for $x>0$ :-)

Comment: Why did you make things complicated with those complex exponentials? Isn't $
y^x  = e^{x\log y}$?

Comment: in order to write it in the form $cos(ixln(y))−isin(ixln(y))$ @Gary

Comment: But it is just $$
\cosh (x\log y) + \sinh (x\log y) = e^{x\log y} .
$$ How would it help?

Comment: Great, i didn't think about it, thank you by the way @Gary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unable to proceed analytically I used numerical integration after logarithmic differentiation.

Take logs and differentiate
$$ \log y' = x \log y,\; \dfrac{y^{''}}{y'}= \log y + \dfrac{x y{'}}{y}$$

The ode is (primes differentiation with respect to $x$ )

$$ \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}= y'\;\big[ \log \;y + \dfrac{xy^{'}}{y} \big] $$

with BC for two curves: $( x=0, y'=1, y_i= (5,9,18,25)\;) $

The Boundary condition $ x=0, y'=1 $  for all $y_i$ *compels* adoption of ode to be of next higher order i.e., *second order*.

[image]

Curve terminates at $y_{max}$  due to log singularity.

$y>0$ always. Negative $x-$ axis exists, but not computed /plotted.

EDIT1:

Integrand replotted after minor error (of no concern here). The computation errors are checked and seen to plot to zero (brown line plot) residue using second order ode.

EDIT2:

This morning even after diligent checks on same program could find no error so far but surprisingly got slightly different $y$ values. I am reporting the same along with the code and the previous graph for anyone to take a look even if qualitatively and checking-wise nothing has really changed.

```
NDSolve[{Y''[x]==Y[x]^x*(Log[Y[x]]+x 
Y[x]^x/Y[x]),Y[0]==5,Y'[0]==1},Y,{x,0,1.715028}];
y[u_]=Y[u]/.First[%];
Res[u_]:=y'[u]-y[u]^u;
g5=Plot[{y[x],Res[x]},{x,0,1.715027}]
FindRoot[y[xu]==20.,{xu,1.3}]
```

The four curves have BC:
$$ (y_i,x_{max})=\big[(5,1.715028),(9,1.66261),(18,1.609705),(25,1.58755)\big]$$

EDIT3:

The matter of [Output Difference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225630/ode-output-variation-in-fracdydx-yx-solution/225677#225677) is not acceptable. So it has been posed at the StackExchange `Mathematica` site with link to this problem in this site ...analysis on-going.

Comment: Why did you have to convert it to a second-order ODE? It makes the problem look harder than it should be. Also, your two upper curves seem suspiciously low, see my take at the original first-order ODE: https://i.imgur.com/xssxUFV.png

Comment: Thank you. I rechecked my work and obtained $x_{max}= (1.715028,1.66261,1/609705,1.58755) $ corresponding four earlier same start values $x_i$ shown in the graph. Please note that using second order ode  the graphs are more accurate confirmed by associated errors plotting to zero.

Comment: Did you check the error computed by first orders separately@Rusian? They appear too big in comparison. If you wish I shall link second order  listing of my code.

Comment: Here's the plot of the relative error: https://i.imgur.com/pk3Lrjx.png

Comment: Relative error is ok. My result also gives zero error. All your  plots have the  same $ y_{max} ?$ .. little strange. Let me check once again.

Comment: $y_{\text{max}}$ in my plots is limited by `PlotRange`. It doesn't make much sense, since it's the value at which the solver gave up due to the singularity close to corresponding value of $x$. Actual value of $y_{\text{max}}$ is very large, far larger than can be usefully shown on a linear-scale plot.

Comment: @Rusian Setting a range that *excludes* what you are looking for !

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not looking at the infinity at which the value of $y$ terminates. It doesn't make any sense. I'm looking at the curve, which is normally interesting not _at_ the singularity where the function is unbounded, but somewhere away from it. (BTW, 4th letter of my username is lowercase L, not i.)

Comment: @Ruslan There is a small error vexing me.. I reported as is. ( Also sorry, oversight spelling your name ).

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly error you keep mentioning. If it's a problem with your use of Mathematica, you might want to ask at Mathematica.SE

Comment: So @Ruslan.. as you suggested also I have referred the matter to SE Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an interesting point about the ode is the essential singularity at $(0,0)$ which separates solutions into domains.  As mentioned by @yves-daoust, $y(x)\equiv 0$, $x>0$ is a solution. If instead you take an initial condition $y(0)=\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ the solution explodes in finite positive time. Furthermore, the explosion time has a well-defined linit as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.  Numerically I find that the max time before explosion is $x_{\rm max}=2.10958799...$
You may find this by integrating the reciprocal ode:
$$ \frac{dx}{dy} = y^{-x} $$
from $0^+$ to $\infty$, with initial condition $x(0^+)=0$.